# Java return value not as expected

Tags: java

I am new Java programmer. I am writing simple program to calculate area of the rectangle.You get to input the width and height of the rectangle, but issue is whatever values I enter, the area value is always returning zero. How can i fix this issue. Please have look at my cde.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Shape {
    private int area;
    private int width;
    private int length;
    private String name;

    public String shapeName() {
     Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.print("Enter shape name: ");
     String name = scanner.nextLine();
     return name;
    }

    public int area() {
     Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.print("Enter width: ");
     String width = scanner.nextLine();  
     System.out.print("Enter height: ");
     String height = scanner.nextLine();
     return this.width * this.length;       
    }
}
public class Example1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Shape shape = new Shape();
        System.out.println("Shape is " + shape.shapeName());
        System.out.println("It's area is " + shape.area());
    }
}
```

Thanks... have a great day! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are not assigning the input to your class variables:

```
private int width;
private int length;
```

But to your method local variables `String width` and `String length`.

So the line `return this.width * this.length;` will return `0` because both `this.width` and `this.length` weren't changed so they are `0` because in Java `int` is  by default initialized to `0`.

You should assign the input to your class variables.

```
 public int area() {
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("Enter width: ");
      width = scanner.nextInt();  
      System.out.print("Enter height: ");
      length = scanner.nextInt();
      return width * length;       
}
```

**Note:**

Use `Scanner.nextInt()` to get `int` values instead of `Scanner.nextLine()` which will return a `String`, otherwise you should parse these Strings back to `int`.

Comment: took the words out of my mouth :)

Comment: @arcee - you will need to convert the input from String into long. Long.parseLong(inputString) should do it.

Comment: There are a lot of ninjas in this site

Comment: @MinhKieu Yes thank you, and I already stated that `nextInt()` should be used.

Comment: Oh I see now. Lol! Thanks so much. Is there a need for a constructor for this code? :)

Comment: @Acree a Java class has a default no-arguments constructor, the one you used in your Example but you can add a constructor so you can pass the `name`, `height`, `length` and ` width` parameters to it when you create your `Shape` object.

Answer (score 0):

```
     String width = scanner.nextLine();  
     System.out.print("Enter height: ");
     String height = scanner.nextLine();
     return this.width * this.length;       
    }
```

Here you are putting the width in two locals variables, and the return the mul of the property width and height, that are different variables. Try with

```
this.width = scanner.nextInt();
System.out.print("Enter height: ");
this.height = scanner.nextInt();
return this.width * this.length;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assigning value to local new variable means,

this.width and this.length is not used and hence returning 0

```
public int area() {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter width: ");
    this.width = scanner.nextInt();  
    System.out.print("Enter height: ");
    this.height = scanner.nextInt();
    return this.width * this.length;       
}
```

Comment: This won't work, because scanner.nextLine();  returns a String, and width is int. Use scanner.nextInt()

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this in the class Shape.

You need to initialize global variables *width* and *length* using *this* keyword

```
class Shape {
private int area;
private int width;
private int length;
private String name;

public String shapeName() {
 Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
 System.out.print("Enter shape name: ");
 String name = scanner.nextLine();
 return name;
}

public int area() {
 Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
 System.out.print("Enter width: ");
 int width = scanner.nextInt();  
 System.out.print("Enter lengtht: ");
 int length = scanner.nextInt();
 this.width = width;
 this.length=length;
 return this.width * this.length;       
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should fix your problem bro!

```
public int area() {
     Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.print("Enter width: ");
     int width = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
     this.width = width;  
     System.out.print("Enter height: ");
     int height = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
     this.height = height;
     return this.width * this.length;       
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code also

```
public double area(){
     Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.print("Enter width: ");
     int width = scanner.nextInt();  
     System.out.print("Enter height: ");
     int height = scanner.nextInt();
      double d=width*height;
     return d;       
    }
```